# Will jmeter function FileToString(path) takes dynamic values

Tags: jmeter

Will jmeter function FileToString(path) takes dynamic values.

I need to use around 400 json files as a input. so planning to use FileToString($fileName}) in body data. By providing the filename column in csv. But it seems Jmeter is checking filename as file instead of getting value from csv.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap your `${fileName}` into [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) function. As per documentation:

> The eval function returns the result of evaluating a string expression.
>
> This allows one to interpolate variable and function references in a string which is stored in a variable.

So you need to change your expression to look like:

```
${__FileToString(${__eval(${fileName})},,)}
```

For more information on JMeter functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.

Comment: 2015/06/06 12:15:08 WARN  - jmeter.functions.FileToString: Could not read file: testname File 'testname' does not exist java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'testname' does not exist. I'm using csv file to save filenames. when i use it is looking for testname as file name not parsing  the filepath. my postbody is ${__FileToString(${__eval(${testname})})}. I have column in csv file as testname

Comment: My mistake it was not taking index. It was parsing because of header I got above error.

Comment: with JMeter 5.0 eval() I get an exception on the file path, the only way it worked was putting in the HTTP Request/body data: `${__FileToString(${RequestBody},,)};`